# Limit of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n(y_n+z_n-x_n)}$, etc.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Someone else asked me this, so unfortunately I do not know its context. Put $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1,2,\sqrt{7})$. Recursively define
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=\sqrt{x_n(y_n+z_n-x_n)}\,, \\
y_{n+1}&=\sqrt{y_n(z_n+x_n-y_n)}\,, \\
z_{n+1}&=\sqrt{z_n(x_n+y_n-z_n)}\,.
\end{align}
Prove that the sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge, and find their limits.

My attempt:

Note that
\begin{align}
y_{n+1}z_{n+1}=\sqrt{y_nz_n(z_n+x_n-y_n)(x_n+y_n-z_n)}=\sqrt{y_nz_n[x_n^2-(y_n-z_n)^2]}\,.
\end{align}
Hence $(y_n-z_n)^2<x_n^2<(y_n+z_n)^2$ implies $(y_{n+1}-z_{n+1})^2<x_{n+1}^2<(y_{n+1}+z_{n+1})^2$. The same is true if $x,y,z$ are permuted. By induction, all $x_n,y_n,z_n$ are well-defined.

Put $u_n=(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ for each $n$. Then
\begin{align}
\|u_n\|^2-\|u_{n+1}\|^2=2[(x_n-y_n)^2+(y_n-z_n)^2+(z_n-x_n)^2]\geq 0\,,
\end{align}
as a decreasing sequence, $\|u_n\|\to\sqrt{3}\cdot\alpha$ as $n\to\infty$ for some $\alpha\geq 0$. The distance from $u_n$ to the line $\ell$ given by $x=y=z$ is
\begin{align}
d(u_n,\ell)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}[(x_n-y_n)^2+(y_n-z_n)^2+(z_n-x_n)^2]}\,,
\end{align}
which converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence $u_n\to(\alpha,\alpha,\alpha)$ as $n\to\infty$.

What I cannot find analytically is the limit of $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Numerical computation shows that $\alpha$ should be $\sqrt{2}$. However, $\alpha$ is dependent on the choice of $u_0$, whereas the method above does not.

Comment: I suppose your attempt is very good  and cleanly written. I do not think this question requires context.

Comment: (Note : I mean above that the attempt is sufficient to count as context so the question does not require *further* context).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspected something deeper was going on. Indeed, if we just substitute $L$ into the recursions, we get trivial equations. So clearly we can't work our way out that easily!

I've often seen situations where *invariants* come in useful. Given a sequence $x_n$, a function $f$ such that $f(x_n) = f(x_{n+1})$ for all $n$ is called an invariant of the sequence.

The key thing, is that if $f$ is continuous then $f(x_0) = f(x_1)=\ldots = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n)$, and therefore we may be able to use the nature of preimages of $f$ to calculate our answer.

---

The first thing I did was write Python code to simulate the situation. I just took some arbitrary $a,b,c$ here.

```
from math import *

def checkone() :

a = 3

b = 7

c = sqrt(61)

for i in range(100) :

    d = a

    e = b

    f = c

    a = sqrt(d*(f+e-d))

    b = sqrt(e*(f+d-e))

    c = sqrt(f*(d+e-f))

    print(str([a,b,c]) + ","+str(a**4+b**4+c**4))

checkone()
```

where I used the $a^4+b^4+c^4$ term to predict that something was going on with the fourth powers of the sequence. I noticed this fourth-power pattern when I saw that we would need to play with quadratics of $x_n^2$, which due to the nature of the RHS (the fact that $x_{n+1}^2 = sth. x^2 + sth. x_ny_n $ etc.) meant that I'd have to go a square further.

Call $(L(a,b,c),L(a,b,c),L(a,b,c))$ as the limit obtained from the above. Following some playing around, I first came to the conclusion that :
$$
3L^4(a,b,\sqrt{a^2+b^2}) = 4a^2b^2
$$
(note : I actually used the homogeniety of the relation and realized that it was enough to take $a=1$, so this simplified things) and then by perturbation to the conclusion:
$$
3L^4(a,b,\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c}) = 4a^2b^2-c^2
$$
This then tells me what the limit should be , following a change of subject:
$$
3L^4(a,b,x)  = 2(a^2b^2+b^2x^2+x^2a^2) - a^4-b^4-x^4 \\
$$

---

Now comes the wonderful idea : That quantity, right there on the RHS, is actually invariant.

> Suppose that $x_n,y_n,z_n$ are defined as given. Then :
> $$
> 2(x_{n+1}^2y_{n+1}^2+x_{n+1}^2z_{n+1}^2+y_{n+1}^2z_{n+1}^2) - x_{n+1}^4-y_{n+1}^4-z_{n+1}^4\\ = 2(x_n^2y_n^2+y_n^2z_n^2+z_n^2x_n^2)-x_n^4-y_n^4-z_n^4 
> $$

This is a *non-routine* but fairly ok check to make. So you substitute the recursion where required and make sure things simplify.

Once we make this check, we note that we can, obviously by induction, obtain the statement :

> $$
> 2(x_{n}^2y_{n}^2+x_{n}^2z_{n}^2+y_{n}^2z_{n}^2) - x_{n}^4-y_{n}^4-z_{n}^4\\ = 2(x_0^2y_0^2+y_0^2z_0^2+z_0^2x_0^2)-x_0^4-y_0^4-z_0^4 
> $$

for all $n \geq 1$. Now, the splendid work of the OP has proved that the sequence converges to a limit $(\alpha,\alpha,\alpha)$.

But now, we may take the limit on both sides of the recursion. Indeed, note that if we do so then we get :
$$
3L(x_0,y_0,z_0)^4 = 2(x_0^2y_0^2+y_0^2z_0^2+z_0^2x_0^2)-x_0^4-y_0^4-z_0^4 
$$
and therefore :
$$
\boxed{
L(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \sqrt[4]{\frac{2(x_0^2y_0^2+y_0^2z_0^2+z_0^2x_0^2)-x_0^4-y_0^4-z_0^4}{3}}
}
$$

which gives the correct answer for the case above.

So find invariants, is the lesson. Don't ask me how I'd do this without computing power, though!

Comment: I like your approach, which is worth more than an answer.

Comment: Nice :). I did not understand the "playing around". Do you mean that you guessed the formula of the limit from changing the parameters in your program?

Comment: That's indeed a great lesson. Thank you!

Comment: @QiyuWen You are welcome!

Comment: @Thomas Indeed. Let me elaborate a little. For example, $x_{n+1}^2 = x_ny_n+x_nz_n-x_n^2$. Now, if there is an invariant $f$ such that $f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1},z_{n+1}) = f(x_n,y_n,z_n)$ and it's a polynomial, then it's certainly got to be more than quadratic, because I couldn't see the elimination of the cross terms $x_ny_n$ etc. with merely quadratic $f$. So I squared once more. It also matched with the fact that each time, I was getting $3L^4$ as an integer. This was baffling initially, but as I watched $3L^4$ it became clear what was going on.

Comment: @NN2 Thank you! I suppose this approach helps whenever directly substituting $L$ for the limit doesn't work. In that case, the recurrence is a bit weird : usually we expect recurrences to attract to the same "equilibrium" point ,or diverge, but this recurrence is one that confines itself to a hypersurface. I'm not actually sure of the practical applications of such recurrences, but for example I believe that they are useful for analyzing random processes that are confined to a hypersurface (for example, a random walk on the boundary of a square grid).